# Is there a lattice approximation of a double-covered space?

Tags: group-theory, vector-lattices

We can approximate a manifold with points on a lattice.

For a space which has the symmetries of a double-covered space. (i.e. you have to rotate 720 degrees before you end up at the same place.), is there some extension to lattices which can approximate these spaces?

i.e. a lattice in which you have to rotate 720 degrees before you get back to the original lattice?

Yes, it sounds crazy but this is how fermions work.

Comment: For the question to make sense you should first explain what you mean by approximating manifold by a lattice. I think, what you have in mind is that every smooth (say, compact) manifold admits a triangulation, hence, a cubulation. Then you can map  the graph of this cubulation injectively to the incidence graph of a lattice $Z^n\subset R^n$ for some large $n$. This holds for a finite covering (in particular, double covering)  as well. Hence, if $M'\to M$ is a finite covering, you can lift a cubulation from $M$ to $M'$ and then embed the graph of the latter to the graph of a lattice $Z^n$.

Comment: Maybe you want the symmetry of $M'$ to extend to a symmetry of $Z^n$?